# When navigating to a page from "More" on iOS the toolbar does not show until device orientation is changed

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin.forms, toolbar

I use tabbed page and have way more than 5 items in my TabbedPage (15 of them). Now when each ContentPage I navigate to is in within first 4 items, my toolbar renders correctly, displaying the icon and allowing user to interact. The problem begins when I have to go to "... More" tab.

Once I select one of the ContentPages there I don't see the same Toolbar with ToolbarItems in it. Rotating the device to Landscape and back brings the ToolbarItems back.

I have scoured the internet looking for an answer but  I can't find much about this particular issue.

Could y'all smart folks point me to a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple test but did not reproduce your issue .
[image] [image]

What is the version of Xamarin.Forms ? And What specific device did you test on ?